# Aligning elements

Tags: html, css, alignment

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHFim.png)Hello everyone I am a new code writer and I am confused about aligning two paragraphs right next to each other.

As you see I am trying to align the price to the right side of the product name and I want it to margin itself automatically. But it insists stay under the product name.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.header {
  background-color: darkcyan;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 4px solid black;
}

.container {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 80px;
}

.first-prod {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.second-prod {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 80px;
}

.third-product {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 80px;
}

.images {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 12px;
}

.first-content {
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.fcp1 {
  color: brown;
  width: 74px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.fcp2 {
  color: brown;
  width: 74px;
  margin-left: 160px;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  margin-top: 13px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <h1>Babark Commerce</h1>
  <p>Everything you looking for...</p>
</header>
<div class="container">
  <div class="first-line">
    <div class="first-prod">
      <div class="first-content">
        <img src="watch.jpg" alt="watch" class="images">
        <p class="fcp1">Elegant CASSIO EA0732</p>
        <p class="fcp2">58 £</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="second-prod">
    </div>
    <div class="third-product">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to align items right next to each other. But elements ordered as up-down.

Comment: Please add your HTML to the question as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to align two Paragraph together in a row you can do the following.

```
<span class='text-container'>
  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p>
</span>
```

Then with css

```css
.text-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

[More about flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/flex).